# How to move all files except the newest one to a folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Windows box and a folder containing such files:

```
2010-07-04  20:18                81 in01_Acct_20100704001.r 
2010-07-07  05:45               165 in01_Acct_20100706001.r 
2010-07-07  19:41                82 in01_Acct_20100707001.r 
2010-07-07  10:02                81 in01_Acct_20100707002.r 
2010-07-08  08:31                89 in01_Acct_20100708001.r 
2010-07-10  04:51                82 in01_Acct_20100709001.r
```

and I want to use a batch to periodically move all these files to another folder except the newest one (i.e. in01_Acct_20100709001.r), because this file is sometimes still being written on and moving it might lead file override in the destination folder in the next run of the batch, and causes file content lost.

Any ideas about this case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the latest file always stamped with today's date?

Comment: Yes, but the older ones can also be stamped with today's date.

Comment: Any specifics on resources available? E.G. VBScript, powershell, etc?

Comment: I got the answer: for /F "skip=1" %f IN ('dir /TW /O-D /A-D /B') DO move %f wherever. Thanks all!

Comment: You should put the answer in an answer box, not a comment.  That wau it can be accepted, even if it is from you.  Otherwise, it looks like it was not answered.

Answer (score 1):

Posting suyao's answer here:

```
for /F "skip=1" %f IN ('dir /TW /O-D /A-D /B') DO move %f wherever
```

The simple explanation is that the DIR command has pre-built date sorting in it.

```
/T (has W implied would work as well) sorts based on time Last Written
/O sets the order, -D = By Date/Time, in reverse order
/A-D only entries that are NOT directories (hence files)
/B returns simply the filename
```

The "skip=1" means that the code should ignore the topmost line returned, and since the files were ordered correctly, that would be the most recent file.